# Is it possible to implement a GC.GetAliveInstancesOf<T>() (for use in debugging)?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windbg, garbage-collection, sos

I know this was [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462236/c-is-it-possible-to-iterate-gc-heap), but I'd like to pose a somewhat different question.

Is there any conceivable way to implement GC.GetAliveInstancesOf(), that can be evaluated in Visual Studio Debug Watch window? Sasha Goldstein shows one solution in [this article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/08/17/gc-helper-for-obtaining-live-instances-of-a-type-or-how-i-implemented-gc-getaliveinstancesof-lt-t-gt.aspx), but it requires every class you want to query inherit from a specific base class.

I'll emphasize that I only want to use this method during debugging, so I don't care that the GC may change an object's address in memory during runtime.

One idea might be to somehow harness the **!dumpheap –type command** of SOS, and do some magic trick to create a temporary variable and have it point out to the memory address printed by SOS.

Does anyone have a solution that works?

Comment: Doesn't solve this question, but has background on how to solve from a debugger point of view: http://mcfunley.com/248/the-debugger-extension-part-4-searching-memory

Comment: It can be done. It would take something like 30 seconds a call so you don't want to. Basically, it is done by calling the same routine that !dumpheap calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something very similar to this was [implemented by Alois Kraus](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2012/06/22/150026.aspx) in the [WMemoryProfiler project](https://wmemoryprofiler.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Yes it is not only similar but exactly the idea to use DumpHeap to get the object addresses and then convert them to a managed object reference. You need to play a few tricks to ensure that no GC does happen in the meantime but I have found a way that works.

Comment: @AloisKraus Very interesting stuff, awesome! However, it seems that in WMemoryProfiler you only try to minimize the chance a GC will occur, you don't prevent it in 100% of cases, so there's always a chance your API will throw a catastrophic ExecutionEngineException? Is this accurate?

Comment: Yes there is a slim chance that I get a bogus pointer back. But if I am the only allocating thread then the chances are nearly zero because I am reading the pointers practically with no allocations. From the debugger I do convert the pointer strings to longs via a helper process. Then I can read long values directly into one array and do the pointer conversion.

Answer (score 1):

There is just about nothing that could drag down the garbage collector more than it having to second-guess that some kind of user code could be interested in finding roots that it doesn't own.  Keeping it as snappy as possible is crucial.  For that matter, the only way you could ever see what is being referenced with some kind of confidence is to freeze all threads that might be allocating memory from the garbage collected heap.

Well, that's possible, debuggers do that.  You already know the way Windbg does it.  It however wasn't designed to be a tool that was optimized to track managed objects.  There are other tools that were: memory profilers.  Plenty to choose from, don't try to build your own.  From the freeware (and time-wasting) CLR Profiler, to the 3rd party offerings like Ants and dotTrace and *many* others.  A couple of hundred bucks to solve your problem, there is no way you can do better by yourself for less.

Comment: I don't want to roll my own memory profiler. I want to take an address of an object on the managed heap (that I can get with a tool like windbg), and then somehow get that variable in Visual Studio's Debug Watch window, when all threads are stopped. I didn't understand from your answer whether you think it's impossible or not, and why.

Comment: Having the address of a GC object is of no use.  The garbage collector will move it sooner or later (you don't know when) and you don't know the address anymore.  Unless you have a reference to it that the collector updates.

Comment: Is there a risk that the GC will move the address around while the application is halted at a breakpoint, while evaluating some expression or something like that? If not, then I don't care... Assuming this method will be called from the Debug Watch window, I'll be forced to re-evaluate the method call the next time I break into the debugger anyways.

Comment: No, the collector can't run when the debugger stopped the program.  I suppose you'll want to do whatever you did to get the address the 1st time again the 2nd time.